# Spring-boot application.yaml in Java Standalone App

Tags: java

I was wondering if is there a way to use a file like spring-boot application.yaml from a Java Standalone App, I am searching for similar approach to pun on it environment properties (for example endpoints URLs dev, qa, production)

I'm using gradle as build tool

Comment: What do you mean with a standalone app? A non-web app or a java app that doesn't use spring boot or ????

Comment: Ooops sorry, I mean a simple java console application, neither web-app not spring boot, just a java console application with a main method

Comment: Define console application with or without spring?

Comment: A plain Java App, without spring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it by myself :)
The solution was creating my own task on gradle. Here the steps that I follow:

1. Inside src/main/resources I created as many files as I need:

   - config-dev.yaml
   - config-qa.yaml
   - config-prod.yaml
2. I added a Gradle tasks to choose the corresponding file:

   ```
   task loadConfigFile(type: Copy) {
   def environments = ['dev', 'preprod', 'prod']
   def environment = 'dev';
   if (project.hasProperty('env')) {
       def validParam = environments.contains(env)
       if (validParam) {
           environment = env
       }
   }
   def configFile = "configuration-${environment}.yaml"

   from('src/main/resources/')
   into('src/main/resources/')
   include(configFile)
   rename(configFile, 'application.yaml')
   ```

   }
3. Before to build the project I called the function using doFirst:

   ```
   build.doFirst {
     loadConfigFile()
   }
   ```
4. For finish I should call the build task using a custom variable named env:

   ```
   ../gradlew build -Penv=preproda
   ```

As a result in the src/main/resources I have a configuration file named application.yaml and using snakeyaml I read the config entries, here is demo about the use of snakeyaml http://enriquezrene.com/home/index.php/en/groovy-english/groovy-for-java-developers/57-reading-yaml-files-from-groovy